# Check count of json

Tags: php, arrays, json

i have some json result like this

```
array (
  'status' => 'sukses',
  'msg' => 'Resi Ada',
  'gen_info' => 
  array (
    'awb' => '030003437484',
    'service' => '',
    'date' => '21-07-2014 15:03:27',
    'shipper' => '',
    'shipper_city' => '',
    'receiver' => '',
    'receiver_city' => '',
    'receiver_address' => '',
  ),
  'manifest' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'manifest_date' => '23-07-2014 17:00:00',
      'manifest_desc' => 'Received By : DEDY SASMITA',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'manifest_date' => '23-07-2014 09:25:55',
      'manifest_desc' => 'Ongoing',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'manifest_date' => '22-07-2014 18:10:08',
      'manifest_desc' => 'ARRIVED AT DESTINATION',
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'manifest_date' => '21-07-2014 18:14:56',
      'manifest_desc' => 'Ongoing',
    ),
    4 => 
    array (
      'manifest_date' => '21-07-2014 15:03:27',
      'manifest_desc' => 'DEPART AT TIKI',
    ),
  ),
)
```

i want to know how much count of this json, use this script

```
echo count($data);
```

$data is result of json after decode

but, why the results obtained do not match the number of counts in json file?

Result like this

```
count of json is: 4
```

"4" is count of this json

but, the total count should be "5" right?

count is 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4, so the number is 5

how to fix this?

Comment: Because you're counting the entries of the root array (status, msg, gen_info and manifest). To get what you expect you need to do `count($data->manifest)` or `count($data['manifest'])` depending on if you decode normally or to arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your checking outer array that's why it's giving count as `4` ,use below code to check count of `manifest` like this

```
echo count($data['manifest']);
```

Or if you have object then use

```
echo count($data->manifest);
```

Check this demo : https://eval.in/929009

Answer (score 0):

The count of the json is 4. There are only four elements in it:

status, msg, gen_info, manifest.

I think you are trying to pull the count of the manifest. In this case, simply use

```
echo count($data->manifest) // If you have an object from json_decode
// Or
echo count($data['manifest']) // if you already converted it to an array.
```

Answer (score 0):

It shows the correct output because `$data` has 4 elements (starting from 1).
If you want to count `manifest` you can do like

`echo count($data['manifest']); // outputs 5`